# Random Sampling from Farlie-Gumbel-Morgenstern bivariate exponential distribution

Tags: r, simulation, algorithms, bivariate, extreme-value

I would like to obtain an algorithm for generating iid samples from Farlie-Gumbel-Morgenstern bivariate exponential distribution (as described in the book by Johnson and Kotz as Gumbel's Model II Distribution) along with theoretical justification if possible. Also are there R packages which implement the algorithm ? I came upon the VGAM package which contains functions only for estimating parameters of the distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cdf of a two-dimensional Farlie-Gumbel-Morgenstern distribution is [given by](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.05356.pdf)
$$F(x,y)=\underbrace{(1-e^{\alpha_1x+\beta_1x^2})}_{F_x(x)}\underbrace{(1-e^{\alpha_1x+\beta_1x^2})}_{F_Y(y)}[1+\lambda\,e^{\alpha_1x+\beta_1x^2}\,e^{\alpha_1x+\beta_1x^2}]$$
with $|\lambda|<1$ and $\alpha_i,\beta_i>0$ for $i=1,2$. This implies that, if $(X,Y)\sim F$, then $(F_X(X),F_Y(Y))$ is distributed from the Farlie-Gumbel-Morgenstern copula$$G(u,v)=uv(1+\lambda(1-u)(1-v)$$with uniform marginals. The associated density is$$g(u,v)=1+\lambda(1-2u)(1-2v)$$ meaning that the conditional 
density of $U$ given $V=v$ is also $g(u,v)$ and the corresponding cdf
$$G(u|v)=u+\frac{\lambda}{4}(1-2v)[1-(1-2u)^2]$$Therefore, inverting
$$G(u|v)=\omega\qquad\omega\in(0,1)$$is straightfoward. This suggests the following simulation scheme:

1. Generate $V,W\sim\mathcal U(0,1)$
2. Invert $W=G(U|V)$ to derive $U$
3. Invert $F_X(X)=U$ and $Y=F_Y(V)$ to derive $X$ and $Y$, respectively.